# Highchart World map with pie

Tags: highcharts, position, pie-chart, highmaps

Here is the highchart demo of map with pie charts.
[US map with pie charts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-pies/)

But this map is only for US. Here is my js fiddle.
[World wide map with pie charts](https://jsfiddle.net/irfanbsse/csbdf7vw/)

```
// Add the pies after chart load, optionally with offset and connectors
Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].points, function (state) {
if (!state.id) {
    return; // Skip points with no data, if any
}

var pieOffset = state.pieOffset || {},
    centerLat = parseFloat(state.properties.latitude),
    centerLon = parseFloat(state.properties.longitude);

// Add the pie for this state
chart.addSeries({
    type: 'mappie',
    name: state.id,
    zIndex: 6, // Keep pies above connector lines
    sizeFormatter: function () {
        var yAxis = this.chart.yAxis[0],
            zoomFactor = (yAxis.dataMax - yAxis.dataMin) /
                (yAxis.max - yAxis.min);
        return Math.max(
            this.chart.chartWidth / 45 * zoomFactor, // Min size
            this.chart.chartWidth / 11 * zoomFactor * state.sumVotes / maxVotes
        );
    },
    tooltip: {
        // Use the state tooltip for the pies as well
        pointFormatter: function () {
            return state.series.tooltipOptions.pointFormatter.call({
                id: state.id,
                hoverVotes: this.name,
                demVotes: state.demVotes,
                repVotes: state.repVotes,
                libVotes: state.libVotes,
                grnVotes: state.grnVotes,
                sumVotes: state.sumVotes
            });
        }
    },
    data: [{
        name: 'Democrats',
        y: state.demVotes,
        color: demColor
    }, {
        name: 'Republicans',
        y: state.repVotes,
        color: repColor
    }, {
        name: 'Libertarians',
        y: state.libVotes,
        color: libColor
    }, {
        name: 'Green',
        y: state.grnVotes,
        color: grnColor
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        center: [state.plotX+400, state.plotY]
      }
    }
}, false);

// Draw connector to state center if the pie has been offset
/*  if (pieOffset.drawConnector !== false) {
    var centerPoint = chart.fromLatLonToPoint({
            lat: centerLat,
            lon: centerLon
        }),
        offsetPoint = chart.fromLatLonToPoint({
            lat: centerLat + (pieOffset.lat || 0),
            lon: centerLon + (pieOffset.lon || 0)
        });
    chart.series[2].addPoint({
        name: state.id,
        path: 'M' + offsetPoint.x + ' ' + offsetPoint.y +
            'L' + centerPoint.x + ' ' + centerPoint.y
    }, false);
} */
});
```

I want to show map world wide map where each pie represent a country. Everything is working fine but world.js file dont have lat and long values.due to which i am facing positon issue of pie on each location.i tried using plotx and ploty .but it doesnt works. So is there any way to show pie axactly on the country  area the way it is working US map?

Comment: I think you will have to take the coordinate from another source like [this one](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel/blob/master/src/data/countries.json)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plotX` & `plotY` properties of the region when it doesn't have the lat & lon defined.

Replace these two pieces of code:

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    center: [state.plotX+400, state.plotY]
  }
}
```

---

```
// Handle lat/lon support
if (options.center.lat !== undefined) {
    var point = chart.fromLatLonToPoint(options.center);
    options.center = [
        chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(point.x, true),
        chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(point.y, true)
    ];
}
```

with these ones:

```
center: {
  plotX: state.plotX,
  plotY: state.plotY
}
```

---

```
// Replace lat/lon with plotX/plotY
if (options.center.plotX !== undefined) {
  options.center = [options.center.plotX, options.center.plotY];
}
```

By the way: using `plotOptions` inside series options is not valid. `plotOptions` should be placed in the top level of the chart options structure. Here's more info on that: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k5mdL6vn/

Comment: it does not working.Please check your demo .All pies are at the same location.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that up. I've forgotten to update my fiddle. It works now.

Comment: Thanks alot @kamil kulig. one thing more i want  to discuss. do you know why clicking on legend doesn't hide the pie?and is this possible to set max and min size of pie ?

Comment: **1. Size of the pies**: size for each pie is computed in `sizeFormatter` function. This demo illustrates how to set maximum size of the pie: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/345ot79j/ You can modify this function and provide your custom algorithm. **2. Legend:** Please describe how do you expect the legend work. For example: What should happen when you click on `Republican` legend item?

Comment: on clicking 'Republican' it should hide the republican value from pie or remove the pie where republican is maximum the way currently area behind the pies are disabled on clicking of legends

Comment: Refer to this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vw9h2q2y/ I changed the function responsible for showing/hiding pies - now it hides corresponding slices too. The thing worth mentioning is that this functionality doesn't work in the newest version of Highcharts (6.1.0). In 6.0.7 everything looks fine.

Comment: I reported this issue on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8334

Comment: Thanks alot @kamil Kulig

Comment: is there anyway  to remove white space around the map. currently there is a lot of white space. Highchart margin does not work here.

Comment: This image shows the whole space that's currently reserved for the map: https://imgur.com/a/vBRI53w Highcharts wants to show the whole uncut map initially - that's why there're white-spaces by the sides. Do you want to show the zoomed map initially?

Comment: i was also thinking abt zooming solution.but it hides some area some time anyhow thanks alot for the help